# No module named 'flask' while using Vagrant

Tags: python, flask, vagrant

I am trying to setup Vagrant in my machine(ubuntu 15.10 64bit). and I followed the steps mentioned here [link](https://github.com/paste/fvang)

I am getting error as no Flask found when I run app.py

Am i missing something here? Its mentioned that all packages from requirements will be installed automatically. But I am not able to make it work.

**Steps are as follows:**

Getting started

```
Install Vagrant
```

Clone this repo as your project name:

```
git clone git@github.com:paste/fvang.git NEW-PROJECT-NAME
```

Configure project name and host name in ansible/roles/common/vars/main.yml:

```
project_name: "fvang"
host_name: "fvang.local"
```

Modify your local /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.33.11   fvang.local
```

Build your Vagrant VM:

```
vagrant up
```

Log into the VM via SSH:

```
vagrant ssh
```

Start Flask development server:

```
cd ~/fvang
python app/app.py
```

Comment: Try with `python2` or `python3` instead.

Comment: That dint work. Same output.

Comment: Could you please include the steps you followed in the question instead of as a link - currently the Github link you provided is returning `No server is currently available to service your request.`

Comment: @BrianMorton I have updated the question.

Comment: vagrant is a clean new virtual os. You need to install each and every dependency. Install flask and try

Comment: Without troubleshooting that entire project, there is no way to guess why it doesn't work properly.  Did you see correct output from the ansible provisioner when you ran `vagrant up`?  Does it install the requirements in a virtualenv that you have to activate?  Did you forget to `vagrant ssh` into the virtual machine?

Comment: Try installing everything with `$pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of the FVANG repo, but I don't have the rep to join your chat. I posted a response on the github issue, see here:
https://github.com/paste/fvang/issues/2

I think the Ansible provisioning script failed to complete due to changes in Ansible 2.0. (otherwise Flask would have been installed from `requirements.txt`). You can check which version of Ansible was installed by running `ansible --version`. I will be upgrading the scripts to 2.0 shortly.

Edit --

I just updated the repo to work with Ansible 2.0 and simplified a few things. Everything should work as expected now, give it a shot. You'll probably want to just `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` again.

Comment: Superb. Thanks a lot. Now its working fine. Still I got error while setting up.  Kindly look here [link](http://pastebin.com/6J3fMCRP)

Comment: Seems to be this issue where Ansible has problems writing to Virtualbox's shared directory on Windows:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9526

The ansible script tries to write `gunicorn.conf` into the main project folder. You could create this file yourself from the template at `ansible/roles/gunicorn/templates/gunicorn.conf.j2` and try re-running the provisioning script...

Comment: I will take a look at a different solution tomorrow, maybe moving to `/etc/gunicorn.conf`

Comment: Hi @Pradeepb, I've updated the Ansible config quite a bit, it should avoid the error you are seeing when it is setting up Gunicorn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response :) I will keep you posted if I get any more errors next time.

Answer (score 1):

A vagrant machine as new as a new operating system. You need to install each and every software you need. try this

```
sudo pip install Flask
```

After installation if you need to run the app, then you need to uncomment vagrant's ip
(In Vagrantfile) before accessing vagrant's localhost, it turns out to be `192.168.33.10` generally and port `5000`

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I know this. I just wanted to know why its not getting installed automatically. Because as per the author of repo, It should get installed automatically. Please have a look at the link provided in the question.

Comment: do a `pip freeze` and check what all have been installed

Comment: I got this
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
PyYAML==3.10
ansible==2.0.1.0
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
ecdsa==0.13
html5lib==0.999
paramiko==1.16.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.19.3
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
requests==2.2.1
six==1.5.2
ssh-import-id==3.21
urllib3==1.7.1
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2

Comment: Yep. I agree. I am trying all the options I can to make it install automatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106935/discussion-between-sameera-sy-and-pradeepb).